# How can I get information from the wifi adapter?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I want to create a local webpage on a raspberry pi and be able to use that page to switch between wifi networks.

Where would I start getting a list of available SSIDs and associated info for them? (At this point, I have not selected a language, but would consider Perl, python, or JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` lists the WiFi networks available to the PI.

`sudo` is used to allow super-user (root) access for regular user accounts.

You should use the `visudo` command to edit the sudo configuration file. Usage of any other command or editor may turn sudo unusable and lock you out of any root access!

This line:

```
www-data  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan
```

should allow your webserver-user access to the SSID list command.

Now any script (including bash) may get the list of SSIDs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $iwlist_fh,'-|','sudo iwlist wlan0 scan';
while (<$iwlist_fh>) {
    print "SSID $1 found\n" if /ESSID:"(.+)"/;
}
close $iwlist_fh;
```

Notice: The iwlist command might take some seconds (or longer) to run. You might want to fetch the list asynchronously.

Comment: Nice thanks very much. I can use this to populate a dropdown on a web page. How easy is it to add other elements of the returned data? Like quality, signal strength, etc?

Comment: Run `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` manually to get the full output. Lots of additional information are available.